# A quick question about the additive identity of a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is it always the case that the additive identity annihilates all elements under multiplication? I can't think of an example; my course essentially relies on integers, polynomials, and matrices for most examples of any given concept. I'm curious if there is an example where this is not the case (and avoid erroneous proofs in exercises!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$0 \cdot x = (0+0)\cdot x = 0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x \implies 0 \cdot x = 0$

Answer (score 11):

On one hand
$(a + 0)\cdot b = a \cdot b$

but on the other hand, by the distributive property
$(a + 0)\cdot b = a\cdot b + 0 \cdot b$

so equating the two, we necessarily have
$0\cdot b = 0$.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is true.

For any $a\in R$, $0 \cdot a = (1 - 1)\cdot a = 1\cdot a - 1\cdot a = 0$.